# Laravel storage permission issue on nginx while interacting with other domain apis

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

This is a theoretical question, so please try to understand my problem.

Let me give you a overall scenario I am facing.

I have 2 different panels with 2 different domains both are developed in Laravel framework.

Panel 1: vendor panel (example: vendor_panel.com)
Panel 2: user panel (example: user_panel.com)

Both of these panel communicate with other using apis. that is, vendor panel fetches data from user panel and vice versa. In short both are same applications but with different domain names. I do hope you got my idea.

Now the problem: whenever any panel interacts with other panel, other panel's storage permission get affected, that is when vendor panel fetches data from user panel.

On the user panel I log the event using `Log::info('vendor fetched data successfully')` and vice versa.

Due to this I frequently get 500 error which is not logged by laravel due permission issues.

Please tell me how can I prevent this.

Comment: Are you sure that both panels are running NGINX (and PHP-FPM if applicable) under the same system user?

Comment: @Rehmat yes, both are running under same system user

Comment: It sounds as though you're missing CORS headers.